# Java Java EE Properties files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, properties-file

I am working on a Java EE application. I am writing a unit test for a class. The class retrieves a properties files, reads it. This works in Java EE server environment. But when I run my unit testing for that it shows props file not found. Do I need put the props file in different place when I do unit testing?

```
private void getValidateHandlerProperties() throws Exception {
    logger.debug("enter getValidateHandlerProperties");
    props = LWSupportFactoryImpl.getInstance().getPropertyResource("validateHandler.properties");
    endDate = props.getProperty("endDate");
    cgiURL  = props.getProperty("cgiURL");
    logger.debug("exit getValidateHandlerProperties");
}
```

Comment: `LWSupportFactoryImpl` seems to be a specific implementation, so without having more information it seems like we'd have to guess what `getPropertyResource()` actually does. Is it a JMockit class? If so, please state so in your post.

Comment: If your depending on reading an external file, then it's not really a unit test. You need to remove the static dependency on the LWSupportFactoryImpl (inject it) and then mock it for the unit tests.